# Struggling to implement game states

Tags: javascript

*Before I explain my problem please let me know if I start to waffle at any point because I don't want to waste more time than necessary.*

So as continuation of a college project I'm trying to make a WarioWare style game in which the gameplay changes every N frames. Here's what I've got so far;

```js
//The canvas
let canvas;
//The drawing context
let ctx;
//The size of the board
let boardSize = 20;
let cellSize = 30;
let frame = 0;
//The state of the game
var GameState = "Snake";
//Whether the player is still alive
let alive = true;
//The apple object
let apple = {};
//Score counter
var counter = 0;

//The perameters of the Snake
let snake = {
  directionX: 0,
  directionY: -1,
  segmentList: [
    [10, 10]
  ]
}

//Sets up the game
window.onload = () => {
  //Prints to console apon successful load
  console.log("Loaded script sucessfully!");
  //Set Canvas parameters
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  document.addEventListener('keydown', keyhandler)
  ctx.font = '30px Verdana';
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';

  //Checks the intial state of the game
  if (GameState == "Snake") {
    appleMove();
  }

  draw();

  //Starts the timer which will call the ChangeGame function every 10,000 milseconds (fine-tuning on
  //how many milliseconds we want the player to play each game for until it changes will be required)
  setInterval(ChangeGame, 10000)
}

//Changes which game is currently being played on called
ChangeGame = () => {
  GameState = "MissileCommand";
}

const draw = () => {
  frame++;
  if (frame > 8) {
    frame = 0
    if (GameState == "Snake") {
      updateSnake();
    }
    //if (GameState= "MissileCommand")
    //{
    //updateMissileCommand();
    //}
  }

  //Clear screen
  ctx.fillStyle = '#d5e6ee';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  //Draw the relevent elements depending on the gmae state
  if (GameState == "Snake") {
    //draw the apple
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(apple.x * cellSize, apple.y * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
    //draw the snake
    drawSnake();
  }
  if (GameState == "MissileCommand") {
    drawMortar();
  }

  //Draw score counter
  ctx.fillText(counter, 50, 50)

  if (!alive) {
    ctx.fillText("Game Over", 200, 250)
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

keyhandler = (e) => {
  if (GameState == "Snake") {
    switch (e.key) {
      case "w":
        snake.directionX = 0;
        snake.directionY = -1;
        break;

      case "s":
        snake.directionX = 0;
        snake.directionY = 1;
        break;

      case "a":
        snake.directionX = -1;
        snake.directionY = 0;
        break;

      case "d":
        snake.directionX = 1;
        snake.directionY = 0;
        break;

      default:

        break;
    }
  }
}

updateSnake = () => {
  if (!alive) {
    return
  }
  //update snake

  let x = snake.segmentList[0][0] += snake.directionX;
  let y = snake.segmentList[0][1] += snake.directionY;

  for (let i = 1; i < snake.segmentList.length; i++) {
    if (x == snake.segmentList[i][0] &&
      y == snake.segmentList[i][1]) {
      alive = false;
    }
  }

  //add new head
  snake.segmentList.unshift([x, y])

  //remove tail
  snake.segmentList.pop();

  //Sets the alive state to false when snake collides with edge of screen
  if (x < 0 || x > boardSize - 1 || y < 0 || y > boardSize - 1) {
    alive = false;
    let x = snake.segmentList[0][0] -= snake.directionX;
    let y = snake.segmentList[0][1] -= snake.directionY;
  }

  if (x == apple.x && y == apple.y) {
    snake.segmentList.push([apple.x, apple.y]);
    appleMove();
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);
  }
}

drawSnake = () => {
  //draw snake
  ctx.fillStyle = '#00000'
  for (let segement of snake.segmentList)
    ctx.fillRect(segement[0] * cellSize,
      segement[1] * cellSize,
      cellSize, cellSize)
}

const appleMove = () => {
  apple.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * boardSize);
  apple.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * boardSize);
}

//updateMissileCommand = () =>
//{
//if(!alive){return}
//}

//Draws the barrel of the player's motar in missile command
drawMortar = () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#00000'
  ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 20, 50);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600px" height="600px"></canvas>
<p><u>Controls</u></p>
<p>Use WASD to do anything related to movment and (TBD) to shoot in during Missile Command.</p>
```

Now what I want it to do for now is start off with a game of snake a suddenly switch to just a screen with a single black square which will be a placeholder for another game. But the canvas simply goes blank when it hits that trigger. Is there anything that jumps out to you as something I've done wrong?

*P.S. If anyone reading this knows any good books on JS that would also be a nice help. I don't want to have to keep coming back here every 30 seconds for the most inane things...*

Comment: book-hint: [You don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/README.md) - a book series on GitHub

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not give you a few ideas. Full refund available if useless :D

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

let frameNum = 0;
var ctx;

function onLoaded(evt)
{
    ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
    onAnimate();
}

function onAnimate()
{
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    drawTimerBall(frameNum);
    drawGameFrame(frameNum);
    
    frameNum++;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(onAnimate);
}

function drawGameFrame(frameNum)
{
    let degrees = (frameNum%360.0);
    var outputStr;
    
    // instead of printing a message, you could call different functions
    // here to perform a single frame-paint and key-check for each
    // of the game styles.
    if (degrees < 90)
        outputStr = 'A';
    else if (degrees < 180)
        outputStr = 'b';
    else if (degrees < 270)
        outputStr = '3';
    else
        outputStr = 'Final';
    document.getElementById('gameNumOut').textContent = outputStr;
}


// draws a ball that rotates around some point
// each frame rotates the ball by 1 degree
function drawTimerBall(frameNum)
{
    let pathRadius = 20;
    let margin = 20;
    let centerX = ctx.canvas.width - margin - pathRadius;
    let centerY = margin + pathRadius;
    
    let degrees = (frameNum%360.0);
    let rad = degrees * Math.PI / 180.0;
    let dx = Math.cos(rad) * pathRadius;
    let dy = Math.sin(rad) * pathRadius;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(dx+centerX, dy+centerY, 4, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

```css
canvas
{
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<canvas width=320 height=240></canvas><br>
    Current Game: <span id='gameNumOut'></span>
```